# Get .NET RewriteMap to work for old URL with or without trailing slash

Tags: .net, redirect, web-config, url-rewrite-module, rewritemap

I'm using a RewriteMap in my web.config file to (301) redirect old URLs to new URLs. The rule is currently as follows:

```
    <rule name="Localhost Rewrite Rules" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*\.)?example\.com$" />
        <add input="{lhRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

*Please note, the pattern intentially hard-codes the domain as this is part of a larger set of rules which are specific for each domain name.  So I'm not looking to optimise or rewrite (excuse the pun) the rule in general.*

The rewriteMap.config file contains the following redirect:

```
<rewriteMap name="lhRewrites">
  <add key="/old" value="/new" />
</rewriteMap>
```

Currently the rule works fine when I visit `http://example.com/old` - it redirects to `http://example.com/new`.

However, it doesn't work when the 'old' URL includes a trailing slash i.e. `http://example.com/old/`.  I need it to work regardless of the presence of a trailing slash on the old URL.

I'd prefer not to have to duplicate all of the mapping keys.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it if you will match URL without trailing slash in regexp `^(.*[^/])(\/?)$` and then pass this matched URL into rewrite map. Your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="Localhost Rewrite Rules" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*[^/])(\/?)$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*\.)?example\.com$" />
    <add input="{lhRewrites:/{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the use of `^(.*[^/])(\/?)$` instead of just `^(.*[^/])/?$` ?

Comment: Using `(.*[^/])` for `match url` works for me and can handle multiple trailing slashes.